# Display certain text based off of Data Selection

Tags: vba, ms-access, report

I'm making a form that shows all of the parts in our database (from our master components table named TAGS). All of the values are displaying fine because it's pulling from the TAG table. The thing is, when the table was created, they never entered the descriptions of each component type.

For example, in the table, TagLabel "CON" should have description "Condensers" on the report for clarity sake (some of the tag labels aren't very intuitive).

I'm trying to use VBA code in order to format a textbox (TagDescription) next to the TagLabel box that displays the descriptions based off of what the TagLabel is. The "simple" but horribly tedious solution to this is just going through the TAG table and manually adding in a description column.

I'm trying to do something like this to avoid that:

```
Private Sub Report_Page()
If Me.TagLabel = "CON" Then
    Set Me.TagDescription = "Condensers"
End If
End Sub
```

I'm sure it's just a simple syntax fix, but I've tried a couple things that don't work, such as adding `.value` and `.text` to the end of `Me.TagLabel` etc. Thanks for all your help in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't `Set` values. **Value** assignments are made with the `Let` keyword, or no keyword at all (since `Let` is deprecated/useless anyway). Keep `Set` for **reference** assignments. Strings are values in VBA.

Comment: @Mat's Mug I took out the `Set` and added the `.value` back in, but it still isn't working. Any other suggestions or maybe some sample code?

Comment: `.Value` and `.Text` are *default properties* and, IMHO, it's best that you leave them in and explicitly refer to them. Default properties are an evil source of bugs (not *here in this instance*, but relying on them *will* bite you one day or another). If you break on the `If` condition there and inspect the value of `Me.TagLabel`, does it say `"CON"` *exactly*, without any leading or trailing spaces?

Comment: @Mat's Mug, Yes it does say "CON" exactly... There are another 20 or so components I have to categorize, but I don't think any of them have any spaces included

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably the syntax you're looking for, but I'm sure if if you'll get the effect you want. It sounds like a very ugly solution.

```
Private Sub Report_Page()
    If TagLabel = "CON" Then
       TagDescription = "Condensers"
    End If
End Sub
```

If you're going to go to all the trouble of building a big IF block for each possible TagLabel, you should probably bite the bullet and do it the right way with a lookup table.

Just create a new column in a Tags lookup table and update the tags - much less typing then doing all the code you're talking about. Then it's easy to join the table to the report query and your textbox will fill automatically

Comment: The only difference with OP's code in that code block is that you've dropped the `Me` specifier, which should have basically zero effect.

Comment: Agreed - sometimes it easier for copy/paste and understanding to see the visual isn't it?

Comment: Yep. Could be [codereview.se] me talking, but if I had to maintain that code I'd violently oppose relying on default properties here or anywhere though. Assigning `TagLabel.Value` (or is it `.Text`?) is so much clearer than assigning `TagLabel`, which looks like you could want to be assigning the object reference itself. I hate default properties. `</rant>` ;-)

Comment: Yeah - you're right - for that matter TagDescription could very well be a label needing .Caption to keep it from breaking

Comment: This code isn't working still, unfortunately. I tried adding the `.value` back in as well as `.caption`. Is it an issue with my text box possibly? Does it need to be bound somehow (even though I thought the code would take care of that).

Comment: @ChristinaDocenko the code is your code, as my first comment said - the [excellent] solution this answer is suggesting is to use a lookup table instead of `If..ElseIf` logic.

Comment: So (excuse my noobiness), how would I go about creating the LUT? Create another table with the descriptions and link them or just add another column to the end of my existing table?

Comment: From your original post it sounds like you already have a TAG or TAGS table, no? Does each row have a unique TAG? Or what is the primary key?